# request.getParameter returns truncated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, tomcat7, httprequest

I am sending large UTF-8 text data ( sometimes contains Chinese ) via `jQuery` ajax method. The method is set to `POST`. But at my server side ( i am using tomcat 7 ) whenever i am doing `request.getParameter` it gives truncated data.

Example of data : `var datas = "article={some very long UTF-8 text}&id=234&author=3434`"

My jquery code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: src,
        processData: true,
        data: datas,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

        },
   })
```

By going trough some articles i found that i have to change my connector and set `maxPostSize` and `maxHTTPHeaderSize`. I did all and changed to large values but same results. Please guide me why is this happening and how to solve it ?

Comment: what data you are getting finally on the server side

Comment: @ankur-singhal partial data. The article is not complete only part of it

Answer (score 1):

Apart from increasing the `maxPostSize`, i just changed my data and encoded with `encodeURIComponent`. `request.getParameter` was returning truncated data because it was breaking due to special chars present the UTF-8 text. I changed my data to

```
var datas = "article="+ encodeURIComponent({some very long UTF-8 text})+"&id=234&author=3434"
```

**And at the server side ( Java ) i used**

```
String article = request.getParameter("article");
if(article !=null) // null check is necessary to prevent from exception if value is not sent by client
 article = URLDecoder.decode( article );
```

and things gone working for me.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` method default size is **2M**.

If you use the tomcat as the web container, please try to increase the `maxPostSize`.

```
<Connector
   debug="0"
   acceptCount="100"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   disableUploadTimeout="true"
   port="8080"
   redirectPort="8443"
   enableLookups="false"
   minSpareThreads="25"
   maxSpareThreads="75"
   maxThreads="150"
   maxPostSize="0"
  URIEncoding="GBK"
>
```

As above configuration, set the `maxPostSize` to **0**, means no limit size when post the data.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Input Text Box:<INPUT size="30" type="text" maxlength="30" name="aField" value='<%=stringField%>'>
```

Comment: Can you explain why that code is a solution to the OP's question?

Comment: A jsp expression inside the html5 tag should be braced with single Quotes to avoid getting truncated values while fetching in the next jsp/servlet

Comment: Thanks! You can edit your answer, so that the code and explanation are easily visible and helpful for others.